# create 6 alphanumeric code for unique field

Tags: php, mysql, database

i need to create 6 alphanumeric for primary key in a table , however i just think to make int field with autoincrement and get the max value of that field and process with this code so it can be alphanumeric and stored in different field.. does this idea and code meet the requirement? and is it good? will it always be unique?

```
<?php
    $code = the max value retrieved from the autoincrement int
    function getNextAlphaNumeric($code) {
        $base_ten = base_convert($code,36,10);
        $result = base_convert($base_ten+1,10,36);
        $result = str_pad($result, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $result = strtoupper($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: not transactional == world of pain.

Comment: Why not have a primary key of `CHAR(6)`?

Comment: cus i want it to have autoincrement.. char cant have autoincrement right?

Comment: and i need it to be unique .. is the any way to do that?

Comment: my bad i edit the code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to think about.

1. Create 6 character primary key.
2. Generate code with php
3. Insert it using `INSERT IGNORE`; if no rows affected (not very likely in the beginning), try again.
4. Done. A unique code was added.

Comment: how to generate it? and each generate have to be validate is it unique or not/ is it already in the table? would it be fast?

Comment: Just create a random string; how hard could it be?

Comment: Jack can i ask, i ever seen some post that char primary key is not good for design , they said just use int with auto increment . is that true?

Comment: @user1851384 Depends on the length and the engine you're using; longer keys will naturally create a bigger index and when you use innodb the primary key gets stored with all other indices of that table. But there's no hard rule that you should have an AI PK column. A natural key is often clearer